# Unable to use scan family command on redis

Tags: redis

I have installed redis version 2.4.6. The installation is working perfectly for other commands. But when i try to execute any command from scan family (hsscan,sscan etc) it throughs error saying

> Unknown command 'sscan'

I will be greatfull if anyone can guide me to get this sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [clearly documented](http://redis.io/commands/scan), SCAN and related commands are available since Redis 2.8.0. Redis 2.4.6 is more than 4 years old and the current version is 3.2.0.